# Appending text to the middle of a Strring in EditText

Tags: java, android, string, user-interface, android-edittext

Please have a look at the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

int cursorPosition = edtTEXT.getSelectionStart();

String currentString = edtTEXT.getText().toString().trim();

voiceEdt.append(text.get(0), cursorPosition, cursorPosition+1)
Toast.makeText(VoiceNotes.this, "Status: "+writeInMiddle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My attempt is to append the text to the place where the cursor is located. Most probbly it will be at the middle of a sentence. For an example, take the text "Welcome to abc". If the text is at the beginning of the text *abc* then the new text should get appened at the beginning of the *abc*.

My above code doesn't work, it appends nothing. Anyway, the `edtTEXT` is an `EditText`.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use insert() method instead of append(). see example,

```
    String s = "This a String";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(s);
    buffer.insert(5, "is ");
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    // will give "This is a String"
```